# Subroutine with hash and optional scalar argument

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine with a prototype like this:

```
sub printFoo(%) {
    my (%hashFoo)=@_;
    # do stuff with the hash
}
```

But I would like to optionally pass in a second scalar argument like this:

```
sub printFoo(%;$) {
    my (%hashFoo,$optionalArg)=@_;
    # do stuff with the hash and the optional arg
}
```

I understand that in warning mode this is a no-no, but I'm not sure why.

I suppose I could use a global variable flag, but any advice on how to elegantly accomplish this type of function signature?

Comment: You could pass a reference to the hash instead of the hash itself

Comment: Prototypes are not for creating function signatures, but for having functions behave like built-in functions.  The general advise when it comes to prototypes, is not to use them.  The function will scoop up all of the @_ into %hashFoo.  You could check the length of @_ and pop off the optional  argument before unpacking it into %hashFoo.

Comment: The cleanest solution would be to have the optional argument just be included with the rest of ( foo => bar, baz => 123, special => 3 ) params, and just treat the special parameter specially (with a default if it is not passed in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this counts as elegant, but ...

```
sub printFoo {
    my $optionalArg;
    if (@_ % 2 != 0) {
        $optionalArg = pop @_;
    }
    my %hashFoo = @_;
    ...
}
```

A prototype with a hash reference would also work. You would still invoke the function with a hash, but you have to remember the first hash arg will be received by your sub as a hash reference.

```
sub printFoo (\%;$) {  # call as  printFoo %foo  or  printFoo %foo, 42
    my ($hashFooRef, $optionalArg) = @_;
    my %hashFoo = %$hashFooRef;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Elegantly dealing with an optional parameter:

```
sub do_something {
   my (%params) = @_;
   my $debug = delete $params{debug} || 0;
   # do something with %params...
}
```

Comment: This is close to how I do it personally in almost all of my modules. I accept a single href (instead of a hash) for all of my params. Sometimes I'll accept an additional cref callback as a secondary arg, but I do prefer to accept everything in one struct.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a hash ref as others have suggested as the first arg, then checking the args after they are accepted is trivial:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (a => 1, b => 2,);
my $scalar = 1;

printFoo(\%hash, $scalar);

sub printFoo {
    my ($href, $opt) = @_;

    if(ref $href ne 'HASH' || $opt && ref \$opt ne 'SCALAR'){
        die "Usage: printFoo(hashref, optional_scalar)\n";
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Hakon Haegland about using a hash ref. In order to get more than one argument that you can pick out you'll need to pass in multiple scalars rather than what is essentially a list followed by something else.

I think that this is unrelated to the question of whether or not you should be using prototypes. The warning system did you a favor by flagging this, but I'm 99.44% sure it won't work even if you discard the prototype. You still won't end up with a value in your optional parameter.